# Transform web.config file when creating a release branch

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, web-config

We essentially have two separate development paths:

1. Local → Dev → QA → Prod
2. Local-Release → Dev-Release → QA-Release → Prod

The first path uses our mainline/trunk, the second path is for when we cut a release branch and need to make bug fixes in between releases.

We use config transformations for Dev, QA, Prod, Dev-Release, and QA-Release and this all works great. However, after each time we cut a release branch, we have to manually change the config files for the Local-Release environment (things like changing the connection string from using LocalDB to LocalReleaseDB, etc).

It would be ideal if we could automate this using another transformation file, but we're not publishing anywhere. Is there a trick to get around this? Could we do it at runtime or have a powershell, batch file, or something else run after creating the branch? What do others do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found a viable solution here: http://kfigy.blogspot.com/2010/03/making-visual-studio-2010-webconfig.html

He's using the approach to allow multiple developers to each have their own config settings, but it can also be used to have config settings per branch.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [`SlowCheetah`](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) will give you what you need.

Taken from the `SlowCheetah` website:

> This package allows you to automatically transform your app.config (or any file) when you press F5 in Visual Studio. You can have different transformations based on the build configuration. This will enable you to easily have different app settings, connection strings, etc for Debug versus Release. If you want to transform other files you can do that too.

I haven't ever tried this in a TFS build scenario, but as long as `SlowCheetah` is installed on the build servers, I guess it would work.

Comment: I already use SlowCheetah. Unfortunately, for web projects, it only transforms when you publish or package the application.